# Android layout for specific device not show up

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I prepared for my two devices two different layouts. First I checked the width and height with this code:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
    float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
```

It showed me that, first device has `360dp width and 592dp height` and the second `360dp width and 692dp height`. So I prepared two layouts in such folders `layout-w360dp-h592dp` and `layout-w360dp-h692dp`.

And it turns out the devices don't use the layout that they are dedicated to. `360dp width and 592dp height` device uses default layout and `360dp width and 692dp height` device use layout for `360dp width and 592dp height`.

Where is the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can I know why you tried something like that? I highly recommend you to use Constraint Layout for layouts ! :)

Comment: I tried ConstraintLayout but it does not work as I expect it is not ideal. But the question is why this qualifiers does not work?